# Multiple subnets on VMware host

Tags: networking, vmware-vsphere, vswitch

I have two VMware vSphere 5.1 hosts.

Each host is connected via a switch to gateway 192.168.20.1.

Currently both hosts have their vSwitches using network 192.168.20.0.

I'd like to have the two hosts use different subnets, but still use the same gateway. For example, one vSwitch using 192.168.30.0 but connecting to gateway 192.168.20.1.

Is this possible to configure within vSphere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the way you want.  You just can't have a client use a gateway that's in a different subnet than its IP address, and that's a networking restriction, not a VMware one.

Having said that, why do you care about them using the same gateway?  This makes little sense to me, and I'd suggest that the solution is probably to just forget about having them use the same gateway.

Comment: Yeah, i do not understand why does he need that?

Comment: Ok, how about I look at it this issue from the gateway end which is a Cyberoam router. Can the router interface be tied to two separate IP addresses - 192.168.20.1, 192.168.30.1 ?

Comment: @Ash beats me, we don't do home gear here.  On proper routers, what you're asking about is called a trunk port - allows multiple VLANs (and, by extension, multiple subnets) on the same interface.  On a related note, it sounds like you ought to get some "real" gear to practice with.  Setting up multiple VLANs and an ESXi host on home gear sounds like a freaking nightmare.  (And of course, home setups are off-topic here...)

Comment: Thanks, VLAN looks to be what I require here. I have added a VLAN IP to the Cyberoam interface. Now I just have to figure out the vSphere side. This is not a home environment - it's for a client with only 1 switch & 1 router.

Answer (score -1):

Basically this issue is related to networking, if VxLAN is implemented in your network environment then yes you can assign multiple subnets in VMware otherwise no.